# Retrieving the first letter of firstname in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have to following line of code in my Mongoose query which is retrieving the full name of the user in a name field:

```
populate("reviews.userid",{name:{$concat:["$firstname"," ","$lastname"]}})
```

How could I extend this to retrieve the first letter of the firstname only, followed by a dot and then the full last name?

E.g. for Mary Khan, I want to retrieve M. Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$substr has been deprecated since version 3.4. You can use $substrCP operator to extract first character of the firstname with $toUpper to capitalize it.

```
populate("reviews.userid", {
  name: {
    $concat: [
      { $toUpper: { $substrCP: ["$firstname", 0, 1] } },
      ". ",
      "$lastname"
    ]
  }
})
```

You can read more about $substrCP at `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result by using the $substr operator to extract the first letter of the first name and then concatenate it with the last name.

```js
populate("reviews.userid", {
  name: {
    $concat: [
      { $toUpper: { $substr: ["$firstname", 0, 1] } },
      ". ",
      "$lastname"
    ]
  }
})
```

$toUpper is used to convert the first letter of the first name to uppercase. Now the query will retrieve the first letter of the first name in uppercase, followed by a dot and a space, and then the full last name.